# SpringMVC And jdbc with Angular2

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, jdbc

am fresher working on SpringMVC And jdbc with Angular2 ,in my controller class written some of method for UI controller but Here Save method is not responding in Postman app and remaining all methods working  properly.its displaying "414,404" BadRequest like that Error Saying plz give suggestion anyone for that save method

package com.employee.controller;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.employee.bean.EmployeeDO;
import com.employee.service.EmployeeServices;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeController")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeServices employeeServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/SaveEmployee")
    @ResponseBody
    // CRUD " Create - Post, Read - Get, Update - Put, Delete - Delete
    public EmployeeVO saveEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeVO employeeVO) {
         System.out.println("inside");
         EmployeeDO employeeDO = new EmployeeDO();
         employeeDO.setEmployeeId(employeeVO.getEmployeeId());
         employeeDO.setFirstName(employeeVO.getFirstName());
         employeeDO.setLastName(employeeVO.getLastName());
         employeeDO.setAddress(employeeVO.getAddress());
         employeeDO.setActiveIndicator(employeeVO.getActiveIndicator());
         employeeDO.setLastUpdatedUserId(employeeVO.getLastUpdatedUserId());
         employeeDO.setLastUpdatedTmstmp(employeeVO.getLastUpdatedTmstmp());
         employeeServices.saveEmployee(employeeDO);
        return employeeVO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteEmployee(String employeeId) {
        System.out.println("delete");
        employeeServices.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEmployee2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteEmployeeRecord(String firstName) {
        System.out.println("dele2");
        employeeServices.deleteEmployeeRecordName(firstName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    // @ResponseBody
    public List<EmployeeVO> findEmployees() {
        System.out.println("sysos");
        List<EmployeeDO> employees = employeeServices.findEmployees();
        List<EmployeeVO> employeeVOList = new ArrayList<EmployeeVO>();
        for (EmployeeDO employee : employees) {
            EmployeeVO employeeVO = new EmployeeVO();
            employeeVO.setEmployeeId(employee.getEmployeeId());
            employeeVO.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
            employeeVO.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
            employeeVO.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
            employeeVO.setActiveIndicator(employee.getActiveIndicator());
            employeeVO.setLastUpdatedUserId(employee.getLastUpdatedUserId());
            employeeVO.setLastUpdatedTmstmp(employee.getLastUpdatedTmstmp());
            employeeVOList.add(employeeVO);
        }
        return employeeVOList;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    // @ResponseBody
    public EmployeeVO loadEmployee(String employeeId) {
        EmployeeDO employeeDo = employeeServices.loadEmployee(employeeId);
        EmployeeVO employeeVO = new EmployeeVO();
        employeeVO.setEmployeeId(employeeDo.getEmployeeId());
        employeeVO.setFirstName(employeeDo.getFirstName());
        employeeVO.setAddress(employeeDo.getAddress());
        employeeVO.setActiveIndicator(employeeDo.getActiveIndicator());
        employeeVO.setLastUpdatedUserId(employeeDo.getLastUpdatedUserId());
        employeeVO.setLastUpdatedTmstmp(employeeDo.getLastUpdatedTmstmp());
        return employeeVO;
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 means the URL does not exist. Which URL you are trying to access, and are they available in your application?

Comment: am using this url :http://localhost:8580/Employee/employeeController/saveEmployee?employeeId=5  in  postman app

Comment: I don't see your configuration, so I'm not sure the URL is correct or not. Do similar URLs for other actions work? Do you see the log `System.out.println("inside");` printed out?

Comment: Hi everyone   previously save method  issues is solved as a little bit ,now values every thing is taking  is tacking based on employeeId ,but id was  showing values remaining values are  all null returning ,and its values did't stored in Database ,can any one please suggetion for that resolve.

Comment: {
    "employeeId": "11",
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "address": null,
    "activeIndicator": null,
    "lastUpdatedUserId": null,
    "lastUpdatedTmstmp": null
}

Comment: Can you use Fiddler2 or any tool to track the HTTP request? Were the other fields sent to server?

Comment: For saving to the database, you need to show your employeeService code.

Comment: Hi, fiddler  debugger app is  downloaded  but i don't how  use this ,previously like that same app  postman  i used to store data on  DB, buts its save not working null values